# Detaching object in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a unit test which basically does the following thing:

1. Query for an object based on criteria
2. Change a property value of it
3. Update using WHERE id = ? and an_attr = ?

   ```
   // Given we have data inserted already
   ContextInfo ctx = createContextInfo();
   DocumentDescriptor desc = createDocumentDescriptor(ctx);
   // With status = NOT OK
   desc.setStatus("RESPONSE_NOTOK");
   dao.insert(ctx, desc);
   entityManager.flush();

   // When updating status with the correct last status
   desc = dao.findByDescriptorProperties(ctx, desc.getSelector(),
           desc.getTransaction(), desc.getType(), desc.getClientId());
   desc.setStatus("RESPONSE_OK");
   Query x = entityManager.createQuery("from " + desc.getClass().getSimpleName());
   List<DocumentDescriptor> res = x.getResultList(); // Watch [[THIS]] marker
   dao.updateWithOldTransactionStatus(ctx, desc, "RESPONSE_NOTOK");
   ```

Some how at the marker ([[THIS]]), I see that the Hibernate does this:

```
2019-04-22 12:43:52,418 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Changes must be flushed to space: DocumentDescriptor
2019-04-22 12:43:52,540 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - update DocumentDescriptor set modTime=?, modTransactionId=?, modUser=?, techTransactionId=?, obsolete=?, status=?, docTimestamp=?, version=? where id=?
```

This is not I want, because I only want to update the value along with other attribute as a condition (see the following line). It looks to me that the object (returned by findByDescriptorProperties method) is not detached.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the flush is not happening actually when you are calling `entityManager.flush()`.

Because of the FlushMode hibernate detects potential stale data and flushes the session before the query. Try to set it to MANUAL.

See [Hibernate FlushMode](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html)